# Randomly Shuffle Enumerated list using enumerate package

Tags: lists, environments, enumerate, random

I am building a template for writing exams, and I'd like to randomly shuffle my enumerated lists at compile time.  [The answers to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96645/random-shuffle-itemize) worked for that purpose, however I am using other functions to be able to switch between a 'Student View' and a view of the 'Key', and the solutions provided doesn't work with the functionality of the `enumerate` package which I used when constructing my other functionality.

Here is an MWE, without the randomize functionality

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, enumerate, ifthen, multicol, tikz}

\newif\ifgrading

\newcommand*\circleAns[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,color=ForestGreen] (char) {#1};}}

\makeatletter        
\newcommand{\itemAns}{
    \ifgrading
        \stepcounter{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}
        \item[\circleAns{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\@nameuse{label\@enumctr}}}]
    \else \item
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\gradingtrue
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \itemAns
    \item 
    \item
\end{enumerate}


\gradingfalse
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \itemAns
    \item 
    \item
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Producing the output:

[image]

Ideally, the randomization functionality would allow me to continue using both `\begin{enumerate}[<options>]` and `\itemAns`, and would also allow me to set a seed for the random generation process for repeatability.  Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: I answered a similar question before. Does it help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566202/could-i-do-a-different-automatic-exam-copies-one-for-each-student/566247#566247

Comment: Alan, thank you for your comment, it was helpful to see, though I will be implementing egreg's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can shuffle the answers in a repeatable way, by fixing the seed.
Devise a formula based on the student number to be fed as the seed.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later
\usepackage{enumitem} % much more powerful than enumerate
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circleanswer[1]{%
  \smash{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,color=ForestGreen] (char) {#1};
  }}%
}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\sys_gset_rand_seed:n { 43221+32 } % a fixed number + the student number

\NewDocumentEnvironment{answers}{+b}
 {
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\__shaun_answers_maybecorrect:n {\alph*})]
  \shaun_answers:n { #1 }
  \end{enumerate}
 }{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\grading}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_true:N \g_shaun_answers_grading_bool
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\notgrading}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_shaun_answers_grading_bool
 }

\seq_new:N \l__shaun_answers_seq
\bool_new:N \l__shaun_answers_correct_bool
\bool_new:N \g_shaun_answers_grading_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \shaun_answers:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__shaun_answers_seq { \item } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__shaun_answers_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_shuffle:N \l__shaun_answers_seq
  \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \__shaun_answers_item:
   { \seq_use:Nn \l__shaun_answers_seq { \__shaun_answers_item: } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__shaun_answers_item:
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF +
   { \bool_set_true:N \l__shaun_answers_correct_bool \item }
   { \bool_set_false:N \l__shaun_answers_correct_bool \item }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__shaun_answers_maybecorrect:n
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l__shaun_answers_correct_bool
   {
    \bool_if:NTF \g_shaun_answers_grading_bool { \circleanswer{#1} } { #1 }
   }
   {
    #1
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%\grading
\notgrading

\subsection*{First question}
\begin{answers}
\item+ Correct
\item Incorrect (1)
\item Incorrect (2)
\item Incorrect (3)
\end{answers}

\subsection*{Second question}
\begin{answers}
\item+ Correct
\item Incorrect (1)
\item Incorrect (2)
\item Incorrect (3)
\end{answers}

\end{document}
```

### Grading

[image]

### Not grading

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very elegant solution (as well as for including my name in your solution, it was a very nice touch)

Comment: @Shaun `expl3` functions and variables should always start with a “unique” prefix in order to avoid clashes with other people's code. I often use as prefix the nickname of the person who asked for the code, if possible.

Comment: I am having one problem where I am trying to reference to the answer item using ```\label{}``` and ```\ref{}``` and I am receiving errors.  Would you have any suggestions for implementing this functionality?